# iPhone: I'm trying to draw a blue line, but it turns out red all the time, why?

Tags: iphone

Something with colorspace ? Note; if I draw on the current context directly it turns black; on an bitmap context it turns red.

Example:

```
CGContextRef context;// = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
void *bitmapData = malloc(getWidth()*4*getHeight());
memset(bitmapData, 0, getWidth()*4*getHeight()); 
context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData, getWidth(), getHeight(), 8, 
                       getWidth()*4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [blue CGColor]);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0,0.0 ); 
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 480.0,300.0); 
CGContextStrokePath(context);

CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, bitmapData, getWidth()*4*getHeight(), NULL);
CGColorRenderingIntent intent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;
CGImageRef image2 = CGImageCreate(getWidth(), getHeight(), 8, 32, getWidth()*4, colorSpace, bitmapInfo,
                                   provider, NULL, NO, intent); 

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),rect, image2);
```

Edit (day later);
Ok, I restarted ( = made a new project in XCode, copy/pasted the code from this example) the entire project and then it is working. Anyone any idea how that is possible at all?

Comment: What happens when you try to draw a red or green line?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
[[UIColor blueColor] set];
```

before you stroke.

Comment: Like; 

[[UIColor blueColor] set];  
CGContextStrokePath(context);

?

What does that actually do?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this. I'll bet your problem doesn't reproduce in the simulator.

This is an iPhone endian bug.

See [qa1509](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html) and use the code from listing #2.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I see I am using quite the same params :( And it actually *does* reproduce in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault` to `kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big`, or failing that `kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little`.

Answer (score 0):

Try erasing the context first. Either with `memset(mem, -1, nbytes)` or CG functions.

Comment: Sorry, but how would I do that?

Comment: Why don't you update the original code snippet, that was a bug.

Comment: You mean; not doing memset was a bug? None of the examples has that (also from Apple)

Comment: Your pixels start out undefined, so you need to either memset the mem  or CGContextFillRect the context.

Comment: Thanks! No idea why the examples don't mention that.

Comment: I'm sure they do, but your code looks like it's derived from code that didn't need to: your context was originally the current context, which DID have defined pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got 'blue' from.  Try making blue in place:

```
CGColorRef myBlue = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0,0,1,1);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, myBlue);
```

Comment: blue was created like this ; blue = [UIColor blueColor]; With your code I get a warning that CGColorCreateGenericRGB is deprecated then an error that CGColorCreateGenericRGB is not available.

Comment: Tried this;  float black1[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
 CGColorRef myBlue = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, black1); Still getting only red...